# Wordpress body_class() loads single post css on a blog page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

On my blog landing page the body_class() injects the blog style (http://madgreens.com/blog). But, when a blog page loads, the single-post style is injected (http://www.madgreens.com/blog/2015/02/chicken/).

I did upgrade 4 plugins recently but have moved them to a folder 'plugins-temp' until I sort this out.

Is there a way to force Wordpress to load the correct css on all blog pages?

Comment: A single blog post *is*, a "single-post"...This is the expected behavior. If you don't want it, you can always remove `body_class()` from the `single.php` template (or whatever template is being called).

Comment: That is correct in terms of how Wordpress handles body classes. What is the problem caused by this? A single article/post will always have the class .single

Comment: There was a class, 'blog', that was included in the single post body_class() but at some point was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior of body_class(). If there are other classes that you want in addition to the standard classes, you can add them by:

```
body_class( 'classname' )
```

or

```
body_class( array( 'classname1', 'classname2' ) )
```

So if there is some class you always want, just modify the body_class function in your template to include it.

For more control, you can add a filter in your functions.php file, like so:

```
    function enhanceBodyClass($classes)
    {
        global $post;

        // Add any classes you want to the $classes array
        return $classes;
    }
    add_filter('body_class', 'enhance_body_class');
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to figure out how do I add the body class 'blog' for all single blog posts?

Comment: OK. I added more information to the answer. You could put logic in your functions.php file to check for single blog posts and add the class 'blog' to the array $classes.